# Setup new Debian 11 server - permission denied when trying to login with right permissions

Tags: debian, sshd

I've installed a fresh Debian 11.4.0 image on my server and selected to install the SSH Server thru netinstaller. After configuring the `sshd` I've setup PasswordAuthentication yes, AllowUsers myuserhere.

Since it's a new install, there's no firewall running.

I've tried logging into the newly setup server, but on the client side it throws permission denied errors. When I try to check the logs I find `failed password` attempts in the logs. It does make the connection though, so that's at least working... I copy pasted my password so I'm 100% sure it's the correct password.

What could be wrong here? I have no SELinux or AppArmor enabled on SSH, running on default settings basically.

**UPDATE*

When I set the `LogLevel`to DEBUG3 it pritned out this on the client side (with -vvv):

```
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
```

Comment: The first thing to try is `ssh -vvv` on your client to see if it shows anything useful. If not then set `LogLevel` in your sshd_config to `DEBUG3` or similar.

Comment: I forgot to mention - I've already tried setting `-vvv` on the client side, but haven't tried setting `DEBUG3` on the server side yet

Answer (score 0):

It was my VNC client - it had a different keyboard layout and so "warped" the password out.